# Vercel Content-Type

Tags: php, vercel, response-headers, flightphp

im having problem with vercel deploy that returns status code 200 on errors,
for ex. `Flight::json(["message" => "Authorization is missing"], 403);` will return {"message": "Authorization is missing"} with code 200. I think problem is that vercel has content type of text, and ignores error code sent. This is my vercel.json but it does not work, how can I get correct error codes btw on localhost everything works as itended.

```
{
    "functions": {
    "api/*.php": {
      "runtime": "vercel-php@0.6.0"
    }
  },
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "/api/index.php",
      "methods": ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS"],
      "headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://keytrack-edu-front.vercel.app",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```